# Proof of a slight detail in the proof of multiplicative groups $\mathbb{R}−\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{C}−\{0\}$ are not isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing

I have seen this answer, [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/620495/711852).

To prove multiplicative groups $\mathbb{R}−\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{C}−\{0\}$ are not isomorphic, they have used the fact that if $\varphi:G \to H$ is an isomorphism then for all $x \in G$.

We have $|x|=|\varphi(x)|$. So let there is isomorphism $\varphi$ between the  multiplicative groups $\mathbb{R}−\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{C}−\{0\}$. Now $i \in \mathbb{C}−\{0\}$ has order $4$ as $i^4=1 so |i|=4$. But there is no element of order $4$ in   $\mathbb{R}−\{0\}$. So there is no isomorphism between these multiplicative group. And in that answer the proof ends here.

But I think we have to proof the statement that there doesn't exist element of order $4$ in $\mathbb{R}−\{0\}$. So suppose there does exist element $x \in \mathbb{R}−\{0\}$ such that $|x|=4$. Now $x^4=1$. Now as $x \in \mathbb{R}−\{0\}$ so we can treat this $x$ as $4-th$ root of unity, so the roots are $1, \alpha,{\alpha}^2,{\alpha}^3$ where $\alpha=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{4}}$.  But  $\alpha,,{\alpha}^3 \notin \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ and $|1|=1\neq 4$ and $|{\alpha}^2|=|-1|=2$. So none of the roots have order $4$. So there doesn't exist element of order $4$ in $\mathbb{R}−\{0\}$.

Is it correct now?

Comment: $\alpha^2=-1\in\mathbb R$ but it has order $2$. An easier way to solver $x^4=1$ is just to factor $x^4-1=(x^2+1)(x^2-1)=0$ and $x^2+1>0$ over $\mathbb R$, hence $x^2=1$, $x=\pm 1$.

Comment: @Justauser oh okay thanks. now i have edited that$ |{\alpha}^2|=2$

Comment: $C_n=\{z\in \Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\}: z^n=1\}$ cyclic group of order $n$ but only elements of $\Bbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ of finite orders are $\pm 1$

Comment: @Alexander Now it looks good, but I still prefer the factorization.

Comment: Just a comment: it can be confusing to use the notation $|x|$ to denote the order of an element when that element is a real/complex number, since it's easy to confuse it with the norm.